# R, RPostgreSQL: a vector in a query

Tags: sql, r, rpostgresql

Using RPostgreSQL package I have to do a query with a `vector` in the `string`:

```
dbGetQuery(con, "select from id_table where id_user in tmp")
```

Where `tmp` should be a list or a vector of length= 10k, how can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: You might need dynamic SQL (like the answers show), but be **extremely** careful: it can open you to SQL Injection.  If you have bulk upload utilities, you might try inserting to a temp table first that you can join to (especially if you have that many values).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use paste0. Here is an example where I take the state.abb dataset

```
valid_state_logic=paste0("(",paste0("'",state.abb,"'", collapse=","),")")

print(valid_state_logic)
[1] "('DC','AL','AK','AZ','AR','CA','CO','CT','DE','FL','GA','HI','ID','IL','IN','IA','KS','KY','LA','ME','MD','MA','MI','MN','MS','MO','MT','NE','NV','NH','NJ','NM','NY','NC','ND','OH','OK','OR','PA','RI','SC','SD','TN','TX','UT','VT','VA','WA','WV','WI','WY')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
query = sprintf("select * from id_table where id_user in (%s)", paste("'",tmp, "'",collapse=","))

dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

Hope this helps.